# how to modify GOPATH in powershell

Tags: powershell, go

I am trying to add my project directory to GOPATH, in linux I can do

`export GOPATH=$HOME/mygo`   in ~/.bashrc

what is the equivalence in powershell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should follow the way you set any Environment variable with Powershell (as described in [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx)):

If you want it permanent (ie will apply for any future shell):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("GOPATH", "C:\Your\Path", "User")
```

> One thing to watch out for: when we used `SetEnvironmentVariable` to create a new user- or machine-level environment variable that variable didn’t always show up when we ran this command in Windows PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

> Or at least it didn’t show up until we restarted PowerShell. (Or started up a new instance of PowerShell.)
>   However, we could retrieve the value of the new variable at any time by using this command:

```
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("GOPATH","User")
```

---

If you want it for just the current shell, as mentioned in [cmotley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172023/cmotley)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12587758/6309) and detailed in the same article:

```
$env:GOPATH = "C:\Your\Path"
```

As [Jaykul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8718/jaykul) comments, setting that line in your `%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` is the equivalent of an export in `~\.bashrc`:
See "[Windows PowerShell Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)".
(There are actually 4 profiles, the one profile mentioned applies only to the current user, but affects all shells)

Comment: Because you're bypassing the drive when you set the item, why would you do that? You can `Set-Content Env:GOPATH $Home\mygo` or use the short variable notation for path access and do: `$Env:GOPATH = "$HOME\mygo"` as @cmotley suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you could do this:

`$env:GOPATH = "$HOME\mygo"`

Comment: Doing that in your ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1 is the equivalent of an export in ~\.bashrc