# Beego (Golang): Create new project via CLI in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, go, web-frameworks, beego

I wanted to play with the Beego webframework. A simple command in the shell can setup a new project directory. If I run the following commandin Window's Powershell I get an error, because the command is unknown:

`bee new beego_project`

How can I register this command to make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your environment variables are correctly set in your Powershell setup.
See for instance "[how to modify `GOPATH` in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12587253/6309)"

- `GOPATH` needs to be set
- `%GOPAHT%\bin` needs to be added to the `PATH` and `bee` must be in that folder.

Note that you can set those variables in your `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1`, which is similar to  a `~\.bashrc`.

The OP adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364388/beego-golang-create-new-project-via-cli-in-windows/28369468?noredirect=1#comment45089636_28369468):

> I just needed to add `%GOPATH%\bin` to the `%PATH%` variable.
>   Now it works also under `%GOPATH%`

Comment: The %GOPATH% and %GOPATH%/bin paths working fine. The weird thing is, that I can do the following, if I'm in the %GOPATH%/src folder: =>  ` ..\bin\bee new project_name`   <=           


Bee.exe is present but I can't call it, if I'm located in %GOPATH%.


**Stackoverflow doesn't seem to use my formating**

Comment: "bee is present but I can't call it": do you mean you get the same error message, even when you do a `..\bin\bee bew project_name` from `%GOPATH%\src`? Or is it working in that specific case?

Comment: I can create a beego project with the shown command inside the /src dir but **can't** do it under %GOPATH%. The error message says, a cmdlet with the name bee can't be found.

Comment: @user3147268 that looks like a command discovery issue (as in http://powershell.cz/2012/12/07/last-modified-date-brainteaser/, mentioned from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19579529/6309). In your Powershell session, does your `%PATH%` includes `%GOPATH%\bin`?

Comment: I just needed to add %GOPATH%\bin to the %PATH% variable. Now it works also under %GOPATH%. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @user3147268 Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.